# Multiple Models in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create multiple models in Devise (using Ruby 2.0, Rails 4).  I have searched Stack Overflow and tried Google, but most people end up using inheritance or CanCan.

The problem is that I need two entirely different models to be able to sign up and use my website, in two entirely different ways - one uses email or username to log in, and has all sorts of management abilities (such as seeing graphs of MobileUser usage, etc).  The other will only access from a mobile device, uses a phone number to log in, and has a much simpler interface.

I tried to run Devise for both ('rails g devise WebUser' and 'rails g devise MobileUser').  I now have tables and columns for both, but only have routes and a model for the WebUser. I tried manually adding routes and a model for the MobileUser, but nothing works - the model doesn't connect to the table, the routes produce runtime errors ('WebUser does not respond to 'devise' method).

Everything I've read indicates that I *can* get Devise to work for two models on my one website - how do I implement this?

My routes:

```
Mailer::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :web_users
  # devise_for :mobile_users (doesn't work, so it is commented out)

  resources 'web_users', only: [:show, :index]
  resources 'mobile_users', only: [:show, :index]

  root 'static_pages#home'

  match '/contact',  to: 'static_pages#contact',  via: 'get'
  match '/faq',      to: 'static_pages#faq',      via: 'get'
end
```

Comment: sounds like a headache. is one of them an all-powerful admin or do these truly reflect different subsets?

Comment: These are two different subsets.  Similar to in MailChimp, where the company sends the email, views charts indicating who received the email, can manage who they send it to, etc... but the recipient only views the email - no controls, no other pages, nothing.  Except for mine, both have to log in - the WebUser with email, the MobileUser with phone number.

Comment: Can you show your routes?  I use devise for multiple models without a problem so I'm either misunderstanding your goal or need more information to advise.

Comment: added to my original post

Comment: Is your goal to have 2 separate sign_in pages, 1 for each model?

Comment: Yes, it would be much easier to have two separate sign in pages, given the difference in their log-in information.

Comment: Could you do this using something like Pundit for roles. i.e. 1 "user" model but with multiple different roles (Mobile, Web, Admin, etc)?

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a very old question but maybe it will help to someone now in 2019 that Devise supports [devise_group](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/Helpers/ClassMethods:devise_group).

Thins makes really easy to work with multiple Devise models. I have three different devise models as show below:

**User.rb**

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :messages

    # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

**Organizer.rb**

```rb
class Organizer < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :organizer_profile, dependent: :destroy, autosave: true, inverse_of: :organizer
    has_many :brochures, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :messages, as: :messageable

    # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
end
```

**Sponsor.rb**

```rb
class Sponsor < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :sponsor_profile, dependent: :destroy, autosave: true, inverse_of: :sponsor
    has_many :sponsorings
    has_many :brochures, through: :sponsorings

    # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

    scope :approved, -> { where(approved: true) }

    # Allow saving of attributes on associated records through the parent,
    # :autosave option is automatically enabled on every association
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :sponsor_profile
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    # Deviseable resources
    devise_for :organizers, controllers: {registrations: "organizers/registrations"}
    devise_for :sponsors, controllers: {registrations: "sponsors/registrations"}
    devise_for :users

    root "welcome#index"
end
```

Now I can not use the same `authenticate_user!`, `user_signed_in?` or even `current_user`. So now, how can I know if any user is logged in? We may need to do something like `user_signed_in? || organizer_signed_in? || sponsor_signed_in?` but that's too much repeating code.

Thanks to `devise_group` option, we can simplify this workflow!

In your `application_controller.rb` add this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    # Devise working with multiple models.
    # Define authentication filters and accessor helpers for a group of mappings.
    devise_group :member, contains: [:organizer, :sponsor, :user]

    private

    def pundit_user
        # Make Pundit to use whichever Devise model [Organizer, Sponsor, User] as the 'current_user'
        # Just by using the offered helper method from Devise, 'devise_group' feature
        current_member
    end
end
```

Now you can use universal helpers `authenticate_member!`, `member_signed_in?` or even `current_member` to validate any Devise user when required. Or you can still user separated helper for each type of Devise user as normal.

Hope it could be useful for somebody!

Comment: I didn't know devise group and it was exactly what I was looking for. Also note you can call "current_members" (plural) to get all members currently signed in on your sessions across those models.

Comment: @TimBrandes Hey! That's a good catch up for `current_members` the plural. But I do not know how it comes useful, not sure about a scenario to use this helper. 

Comment: I have a model for uploads. An upload can belong to an admin, employee or partner and can have access rights for each of them. Each of those has their own devise model. When checking if an upload can be accessed, the current_members method comes in handy to check if current_members include one of the allowed devise models for access control! Might be better than checking if admin_signed_in? || employee_signed_in?, ...

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like a possible scenario but I'm not sure, maybe it also can be handled by Pundit or CanCanCan. But thanks for sharing!

Comment: Yes, if you're using a separate lib for authorization then I'd go with that, too. Another use case would be a public portal that is shared by multiple devise models. By checking current_members it would be very easy to display message only if any of the members is logged in.

Comment: Yup, you're right about that! I'm sure I will find a good scenario to work with this Devise feature now that I know about its existence. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Following excerpts are from the devise gem readme:

Use following to generate your model:

```
rails generate devise MODEL
```

Use following to define custom views:

```
rails generate devise:views MODELS
```

Use following to generate custom controllers:

```
rails generate devise:controllers [scope]
```

and then in your routes

```
devise_for :MODELS, controllers: { sessions: "MODELS/sessions" }
```

I have been using the devise with multiple models using these steps without any difficulty...